# In Rails, how do I redirect back to the original page after login success with omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, omniauth

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and omniauth.  I have this partial included on a couple of my pages

```
    <div id="loginLogos">
            <%= link_to image_tag("google_plus_icon.jpg", :border => 0, :alt => 'Google'), '/auth/google' %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png", :border => 0, :alt => 'Facebook'), '/auth/facebook' %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("twitter_icon.png", :border => 0, :alt => 'Twitter'), '/auth/twitter' %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("linkedin.png", :border => 0, :alt => 'LinkedIn'), '/auth/linkedin' %>
    </div>
```

After someone successfully signs in, I would like them to be redirected back to the page that spawned the above partial.  I read in another answer that I need to have this method

```
def store_return_to
  session[:return_to] = request.url
end
```

but the answer does not specify where to put it.  Do I need to include it in my application controller or every controller that serves a view that renders the partial I reference?

Answer (score 0):

be sure to specify your callback in initializer.
for example for facebook:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "app_id", "app_secret",
    scope: 'public_profile,email,manage_pages,pages_show_list', info_fields: 'id,name,link', display: 'popup', callback_path: '/stores/facebook_callback'

end
```

and don't forget to add it to the routes ;)

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer.  Where is "/stores/facebook_callback" defined and what is the content of it?

Comment: that's a custom action you define yourself (you can name it as you want). the response after the auth will be handled in there.